# GitHub Actions | Incorrect File Type | Tar

Tags: ubuntu, github, github-actions, tar

I have a GH actions where I upload a tar file to JFROG and then download to extract to process it further.

If I put the upload and download code is same yml file, the file type is shown as tar gz and I'm able to unzip as well.

However, if I put the download code in different yml files, then the file type is being shown as JSON data.

I checked permissions, I see below:

```
Different File: -rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker 91 Aug 13 02:57 331bdb1.tar.gz
Same File: -rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker 7115 Aug 13 02:57 331bdb1.tar.gz
```

What does the value 91, 7115 represent?

Any idea? I have already verified the download and unzip commands, they are exactly the same.